# FlexBox Column Layout - adjust height to be the same size for x-axis

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout that displays the data in column format. I want to keep the x-axis(rows) the same height across the columns.  If one item in the flex column has more text then the other columns they get out of wack.

See the code pen [codepen link](https://codepen.io/jdiapps/pen/JNwXPx)

How do I get the item height to be the same across each x-axis(row).

```css
.Grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word !important;  
}
.Grid-column {
  //flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding:0;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-wrap: break-word !important; 
  
}
.Grid-cell {
   width: 100%;
   flex: 1;
   word-wrap: break-word !important;   
   min-width: 50%;
  padding:0 1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.Grid-cell:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: lightgray;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;   
}  

.Grid-row:first-child {
  background:dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.Grid-cell:first-child {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top:1em;
}
.Grid-cell:first-child {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id=event-history-view>
    <div class="Grid">
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">1Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Brief Descriptionasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `Grid-column`s aren't `display: flex`, so `flex-direction` is not even working. If you simply add `display-flex` to column, they'll stretch vertically, but honestly won't look better.
This is clearly a tabular data and the best way would be to just use tables.

Comment: With the given markup you won't be able to do that without a script. Is a change of your markup possible?

Comment: I noticed you have a previous question and it suffer from the same issue as this one, the markup structure. If you let me know if a markup change is allowed, there is a simple solution to both your questions. If not, tell me why you need this structure and there might be as solution to that, even with a change.

Comment: Yes please change the markup structure.  Thanks